# Fill every blank line with a difference from next line

Tags: windows

```
[00:00.00]  
[00:03.94]A  
[00:06.00]B  
[00:08.18]C  
[00:10.24]D  

[00:12.55]1  
[00:15.18]2  
[00:16.92]3  
[00:19.10]4  

[00:21.29]1A  
[00:23.53]2B  
[00:25.72]3C  
[00:27.91]4D
```

From the following lines, I want every empty line to be filled with a number that is exactly 0.8 less than the next number in brackets. So from the above example it becomes the following:

```
[00:00.00]  
[00:03.94]A  
[00:06.00]B  
[00:08.18]C  
[00:10.24]D  
[00:11.75]
[00:12.55]1  
[00:15.18]2  
[00:16.92]3  
[00:19.10]4  
[00:20.49]
[00:21.29]1A  
[00:23.53]2B  
[00:25.72]3C  
[00:27.91]4D
```

Another important note is that it's a timestamp, so subtracting 0.8 from [01:00.00] should yield [00:59.20]. Is there any software I can do for this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The software you need is called a "programming language". Almost any programming language will do.